# Avoiding loops in dictionary generation from child-parent relationships

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, parent-child

I am trying to create a dictionary tree from child-parent relathionships but the issue here is that the child can contain one of his predecesors generating loops that I would like to avoid.

```
list_child_parent = [(2,1),(3,2),(4,2),(5,3),(6,4),(2,6)]
def make_map(list_child_parent):
    has_parent = set()
    all_items = {}
    for child, parent in list_child_parent:
        if parent not in all_items:
            all_items[parent] = {}
        if child not in all_items:
            all_items[child] = {}
        
        if parent not in all_items[child]:
            all_items[parent][child] = all_items[child]
            has_parent.add(child)
        else:
            continue

    result = {}
    for key, value in all_items.items():
        if key not in has_parent:
            result[key] = value
    return result
make_map(list_child_parent)
```

The code works well if a son contains his father but not if it is the granfather...
I think another approach is needed.

The expected results could be any if it makes sense:
`{1: {2: {3: {5: {}}, 4: {6: {}}}}}`
`{1: {2: {3: {5: {}}, 4: {6: 2}}}}`
`{1: {2: {3: {5: {}}, 4: {6: {2:{}}}}}}`

The current result is:
`{1: {2: {3: {5: {}}, 4: {6: {2: {...}}}}}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a set to keep track of all the children, so that you can make the dict of descendants an empty dict if the current child has previously been a child of another parent:

```
def make_map(list_child_parent):
    mapping = {}
    children = set()
    for child, parent in list_child_parent:
        mapping.setdefault(parent, {})[child] = (
            {} if child in children
            else mapping.setdefault(child, {})
        )
        children.add(child)
    return {
        parent: mapping[parent]
        for parent in mapping.keys() - children
    }
```

so that:

```
make_map([(2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 3), (6, 4), (2, 6)])
```

returns:

```
{1: {2: {3: {5: {}}, 4: {6: {2: {}}}}}}
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHRCsIgFIbv9xTnUsGCthUR9CRjDGmupOXE2UWMPfs6zmlFQd44z/@f7/w6/bCXTmV7baapFg3c@FVUN65JK3tbnS6yrSvNjVCWHhLAhZqW6gxHGMa5MHvQgJVeWELnYtMZLzDw3SAVfCE98Y26RgKm4PfWEm9hOIYWc1OJE0jscGsYQTZ@juOHJB8e0fbiF35Jh/Rof30F0prXtXd6zQh7NwqGaFzuEQYU/lxG3b3D6wFCjKt49ITC6jPxmCTaSGVJ/AcFyRiklAFJGWzcni/nLYPM7TsG@aLvaEnpNyF0BtI/wjQ9AQ)

Comment: @Luis Please edit your question to show a more realistic example. You should also explain much more clearly what the expected result should be. Also: what is the real-world scenario that you are trying to model with this structure?

Comment: Comment deleted @ekhumore.
Sorry for the confusion, the solution from blhsing is completly valid in all my scenarios :) 
Sorry for the inconveniences!